# Is Noah Tronte Neilson's father?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In the TV series [**Dark**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5753856/?ref_=nv_sr_3), in 1953 Agnes and Tronte Neilson move with the 
Tiedemann's because there is a spare room. At one point in time Agnes says that her husband is dead and that he was a priest and we also see that Tronte was burned with cigarette buds indicating that he had a troubled past.

Could this be an indication that Noah was indeed Tronte's dad?

Comment: I highly recommend this [link](https://dark.netflix.io/en), which thoroughly explains the family tree, ajdusted to what episode you're currently watching (to avoid spoilers)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Updated June 24th 2019 to reflect new information in Season 2** (everything below until update remains speculation based on Season 1)

**There is currently no definitive answer.**

The show definitely leaves some *hints* that Noah is Tronte's father.  Agnes talks about her ex being an evil or bad man, along with the points you mentioned.

Combining this with the knowledge that he was a priest; it does sound extremely similar to what we know of Noah.

This has been discussed quite a bit on the [Dark Subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/dark) and I have yet to see anything that can prove without a doubt that he is the father.

It's very possible that it was included as a red herring.  There is a lot of speculation about Noahs past.

I will say that of all the Noah identity theories I've seen proposed, this is generally the easiest to accept and theorize about.  At best we can say it's **possible but unconfirmed**.

**Update June 24th, 2019 (Season 2 spoilers):**

> It seems that based on the evidence from Season 2, Noah is **not** Tronte's father.  We now know that Noah and Agnes are almost definitely not a couple, but are instead bother and sister (there's always a chance this is lies, or that they are brother and sister and *also* have a child; but this doesn't seem that likely).  This would mean someone else is actually the father.  Given that we now know others travel back in time and seem to join with Sic Mundus Creatus Est, I personally believe the speculation that the father is Bartosz, just another piece of the interconnected families of Winden.

Answer (score 4):

After season 3 hope you got the answer. Noah is not the father of Tronte Nielsen.

> The Unknown with the cleft lip, i.e., Jonas Kahnwald and Martha Nielsen's child had fathered Tronte Nielsen. In season 3 we see that The Unknown meets young Tronte and gives, says her knew Tronte's mother long ago and gave him his mother's bracelet. thus it was clear that he was the father of Tronte. This is also confirmed by the family tree chart also in Eva's place. [image]

Comment: In addition Tronte spend time in a orphanage, so this may also be where he got the burns.

Comment: That may be the case either, though I thought It could be his father or mother.